running total based on week numbers



Year-Week
Year - Month
running count of users




21w52
2021-Dec
10


22w01
2022-Jan
20


22w02
2022-Jan
30


22w03
2022-Jan
40


22w04
2022-Jan
50


22w05
2022-Jan
60


22w05
2022-Feb
60


22w06
2022-Feb
65


22w07
2022-Feb
70


22w08
2022-Feb
75


22w09
2022-Feb
80


22w09
2022-Mar
80


22w10
2022-Mar
85



In the above table data, 22w05 and 22w09 is showing for two months because the date range for 22w05 is "January 31, 2022    February 6, 2022" & 2209 is "February 28, 2022  March 6, 2022"
.That particular week count should divide with 5 and. Split the count based on days in the each month.
Below is the example output.



Year-Week
Year - Month
running count of users




21w52
2021-Dec
10


22w01
2022-Jan
20


22w02
2022-Jan
30


22w03
2022-Jan
40


22w04
2022-Jan
50


22w05
2022-Jan
12


22w05
2022-Feb
48


22w06
2022-Feb
65


22w07
2022-Feb
70


22w08
2022-Feb
75


22w09
2022-Feb
16


22w09
2022-Mar
64


22w10
2022-Mar
85




Please paste sample data as copiable text and mark old questions as solved

Please check if this helps. Year-Week Year-Month count of users
22w05 2022-Jan 50
22w05 2022-Feb 50
22w06 2022-Feb 60
22w07 2022-Feb 70
22w08 2022-Feb 85
22w09 2022-Feb 90
22w09 2022-Mar 90
22w10 20222-Mar 100

Update your question with the data in table markdown and mark your old questions as solved

Hi @davidebacci, i have added the data as a text so that you can copy now.
